# GO pg prevent default value

Tags: go, pg

Struct sample

```
type Car struct {
    ID              uint64
    Required        bool                   `pg:"required,notnull"`
    Name            string                 `pg:"name"`
    }
```

Migration:

```
BEGIN;

ALTER TABLE cars ADD COLUMN required BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT true;

END;
```

When I create car struct:

```
car = Car{Name:"Name",Required:false}
```

When i'm trying to add some new car by writing:

```
_, err = r.db.Model(&car).Insert()
```

SQL Query looks like this:

```
INSERT INTO "cars" ("id", "name", "required") VALUES (DEFAULT, "Name", DEFAULT)
```

The main problem that car has required field set as false, but when I inserting it - it changes to DEFAULT (true).

Comment: You're creating the Car with `required` but the struct field is `Required`

Comment: It doesn`t matter) It was my typo

Comment: That SQL query can't be right. `"Name"` is the column `Name`. `'Name'` is the string value `Name`. It should be `VALUES (DEFAULT, 'Name', DEFAULT)`. So what's the real query and the real code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the value `false` will be read as a null value. Because null value your data will be change to the default value (TRUE)

You must change the struct to like this

```
type Car struct {
    ID       uint64
    Required *bool  `pg:"required,notnull,default:true"`
    Name     string `pg:"name"`
}
```

and define struct like this

```
required := false
car = Car{Name:"Name", Required: &required}
```

or you can also use data type `sql.NullBool` in your struct

```
type Car struct {
    ID       uint64
    Required sql.NullBool  `pg:"required,notnull,default:true"`
    Name     string `pg:"name"`
}

car = Car{Name:"Name", Required: sql.NullBool{Bool: false, Valid: true}}
```

Comment: The main problem, is that when I'm trying to add a lot of cars without specifying required field I want it to have required as true. Your solution in this case setting all cars to false(

Comment: @kyrkela add tag default:true to your struct to force value required as true if field not set. I'm already updated my answer